# Prove that $J = \{q(x) \in Q[x] \,|\, q(\sqrt{p}) = 0\}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, with p prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

As it says in the title, but there is a caveat: I cannot use or prove the fact that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}]$ is a field beforehand, since the whole point of the exercise is to prove this from the title statement.

I have been attempting this for a few hours now and have no idea how to proceed. I have proven this sort of thing before, by contradiction, but, in this case, I only managed to get $1 \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}]$...

I'd love a suggestion or an indication of a way to proceed more than an actual proof.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I do know that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{p}] = \{x + y\sqrt{p} \,|\, x, y, \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: I assume that you mean $J = \{q(x) \in \mathbb Q[x] \,|\, q(\sqrt p) = 0 \}.$

Comment: Check if $(x^2-p)$ is a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that $\mathbb Q$ is a field, it follows that $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a PID (principal ideal domain). We may assume therefore that $J = (q(x))$ for some polynomial $q(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $q(\sqrt p) = 0.$ Considering that $\sqrt p$ is a root of $q(x),$ it follows that $x - \sqrt p$ is a factor of $q(x)$ in $\mathbb R[x].$ But by hypothesis that $q(x)$ is in $\mathbb Q[x],$ we must have that $x + \sqrt p$ is also a factor of $q(x)$ in $\mathbb R[x].$ (Why?) We have therefore that $x^2 - p$ is a factor of $q(x)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ so that $J = (q(x)) = (x^2 - p).$

Every prime ideal of a PID is maximal, hence it suffices to show that $J$ is prime. Of course, a principal prime ideal is generated by a single prime element, so it suffices to prove that $x^2 - p$ is prime. Further, the prime elements of a PID (or more generally a UFD) are the same as the  irreducibles, hence it suffices to prove that $x^2 - p$ is irreducible. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I haven't read about prime polynomials yet; this chapter of the book I'm using has so far only mentioned the definition of a Polynomial, their sum and product, and the fact that they form a Euclidian Domain - which is used to prove a couple other results. But honestly, I'm a little fed up by this exercise at this point and the proof seems really straight forward, if irreducible means what I think it does. I'm pretty sure I can finish the proof after a few minutes of reading, now!!

Comment: We say that a polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible if it cannot be written as a product $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ for some polynomials $g$ and $h$ of **strictly** lower degree. One useful fact about polynomials of degree 2 and 3 is that they are irreducible if and only if they do not have a root in the coefficient ring. (To see this, think about how to decompose the integers 2 and 3 as a sum of **strictly** smaller integers; then, think about how a root of $f(x)$ relates to a factor of $f(x).$)